# A Simple Calculator using Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to create a website where the user is asked to type a given number to get the square number and the square root.

This is from index.html:

```html
  <div class="d-flex typeW">

    <form action="add">
    Enter a number : <input type="text" name="num1">

    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </div>
```

This is from the result page (where you can see the result):

```html
<div class="d-flex title2">

    <h2>

    {% block content %}



      {{result}}

    {% endblock %}
    <br><br>
```

This is from view:

```
def add(request):
num1 = int(request.GET["num1"])
return render(request, 'result.html' , {result2: num1 * num1})
```

Now I want to take the square root of that number but I'm not sure how.

How do I take one input and then do two calculations by using two functions?

help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do two calculations in your view and return both results within the context. You can then access all values in the context and render them in the template.

```
import math

def add(request):

    # Get the user input
    num1 = int(request.GET["num1"])

    # Calculate square
    num1_square = num1 ** 2

    # Calculate root 
    num1_root = math.sqrt(num1)

    # return context
    context = {
        'square': num1_square,
        'root': num1_root
    }

    return render(request, 'result.html' , context)
```

```
# template

<div class="d-flex title2">

    <h2>

    {% block content %}

      {{ square }}

      {{ root }}

    {% endblock %}
    <br><br>
```

Comment: Omg you the are best